# Hover info not appearing on shiny ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, hover

Any ideas why my hover isn't working? The different cursor (black cross) is appearing when I hover over but I'm not getting the information. This was working in previous versions, and I haven't altered my hoverOpts sections since then but now it's not working for some reason. I can't supply the data I'm afraid due to confidentiality reasons but here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Transfers Analysis App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
            useShinyjs(),
            id="form",
            pickerInput(inputId = "Day", 
                  label = "Days of Week", 
                  choices = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), selected = data$day[data$day %in% c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')],
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), 
                  multiple = T
            ),
            pickerInput(inputId = "Month", 
                  label = "Months", 
                  choices = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), selected = data$month[data$month %in% c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')],
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), 
                  multiple = T
            ),
            radioButtons("Curves", "Curve",
                                    choices = c("None", "Total", "Outages", "Days After an Outage"),
                                    selected = "None"
            ),

      checkboxInput("Outage", "Show Outages", FALSE),
      checkboxInput("DayAfter", "Show Day After Outages", FALSE),
      actionButton("Reset", "Reset")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1", height = "600px", width = "100%",
                 hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")
      )
    )  
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Day <- input$Day
    Month <- input$Month
    Outage <- input$Outage
    DayAfter <- input$DayAfter
    Curves <- input$Curves
    data <- data[data$day %in% input$Day]
    data <- data[data$month %in% input$Month]
    Reset <- input$Reset

    g <- ggplot(data, aes(Date, NUMBER_OF_TRANSFERS), xlab=("Call Transfers")) + geom_point()  + labs(y = "Call Transfers")

    if (Curves == "Total")
      g <- g + geom_smooth(colour="black") + 
      scale_colour_manual(values="black")
    if (Curves == "Outages")
      g <- g + geom_smooth(data=(data[Outage == "Outage"]), aes(color = (Outage[Outage == "Outage"]))) + 
      scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), values=c( "red", "blue"), name = "Legend") + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
    if (Curves == "Days After an Outage")
      g <- g + geom_smooth(data=(data[DayAfter == "Day After an Outage"]), aes(color = (DayAfter[DayAfter == "Day After an Outage"]))) + 
      scale_colour_manual(values=c( "blue"), name= "Legend") + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
    if ((Outage == TRUE) & (DayAfter == FALSE))
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = Outage))  + 
      scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), name= "Legend", values=c( "black", "red", "blue")) + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
    if ((Outage == FALSE) & (DayAfter == TRUE))
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = DayAfter)) + 
      scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), name= "Legend", values=c("black", "blue", "red")) + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
    if ((Outage == TRUE) & (DayAfter == TRUE))
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = DayAfter2)) + 
      scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), name= "Legend", values=c("purple", "blue", "black", "red")) + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
    if ((Outage == TRUE) & (DayAfter == FALSE) & (Curves == "Days After an Outage"))
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = Outage))  + 
      scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), name= "Legend", values=c( "blue", "black", "red")) + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")
    if ((Outage == TRUE) & (DayAfter == TRUE) & (Curves == "Days After an Outage"))
      g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = DayAfter2))  + 
      scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("Outage", "No Outage", "Day After an Outage", "Both"), name= "Legend", values=c( "purple", "blue", "black", "red")) + 
      theme(legend.position="bottom")

    plot(g)

  })

  observeEvent(
    input$Reset,
    {
      reset("form")
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you add *data* to your post to make it reproducible?

Comment: How do I do that? (new to stackoverflow)

Comment: you can use dput(), just google it.